# How to parse html ul li to array charsequence in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a html view get from asset. But i want to parsing `<ul><li>Category 1</li></ul>` to be charsequence array, so I can put it into listview.

My HTML data:

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li>Category 1</li>
<li>Category 2</li>
<li>Category 3</li>
<li>Category 4</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get result

```
CharSequence[] myList={"Category 1","Category 2","Category 3","Category 4"};
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: refer this link http://blog.andrewpearson.org/2010/07/android-html-parsing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit strange to use a local html asset as a datasource for a listview, but anyway..

To extract the contents of the tags into an charsequence array you could use something like this

```
List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<li>(.+?)</li>").matcher(theStringWithTags);
while (matcher.find()) {
    tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
}

CharSequence[] cs = tagValues.toArray(new CharSequence[tagValues.size()]);
```

Cheers,
 Marcus

Comment: Hi masse, thanks very mucs, this is work. I give you thumb up and true answer. cheers :-)

Comment: Hello, how to passing link, so if setOnItemClickListener go to link, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php) and XPATH.
You can take a look on this examples : 
[Using XPATH and HTML Cleaner to parse HTML / XML](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/)
[Here](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php)

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, problem solved with @Masse, the html cleaner maybe i need it when later i want to get result from http.